# Spring. Creating a custom search based on wildcards

Tags: java, spring, search, wildcard, sql-like

I am new into Spring, though my issue may appear immature.

Here is a big obstacle I have been stuck into. I am trying to choose the right approach to implement search logic based on wildcards, whether to select JDBC, or Hibernate, or JPA and repositories.

I will demonstrate the problem. Let say we have a search form within web page, where someone may put query to retrieve FirstName and LastName, and say for example there are records:

- "Fred Fredrickson"
- "Albert Jameson"
- "Watson Dalbot"

It is possible to use something like *alb*, we should get:

- "Albert Jameson"
- "Watson Dalbot"

or using ????son we expect to get only "Albert Jameson".

Learning Spring I found that "like" clause may be only hardcoded, something like:

@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname like %?1")
  List findByFirstnameEndsWith(String firstname);

in case of using JPA repositories.

I hope my problem has got a bit clearer.

Big thanks in advance for any kind of help or related advice.

Comment: MySQL (and I'm sure the other SQL brethren) has the ability to search for things based on regular expressions. I don't think you want to reinvent the wheel here in Java.

Comment: Yes, MySql itself has this ability, however, you should, say, hardcode all methods in Java, like "findByFirstName" or "findById" or something like that. I might be wrong... How we can tune the method in java getting wildcards from search form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have use JPA with the following example

```
@NamedQuery(name="Profile.getPerson", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.firstName LIKE ?1");

Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Profile.getPerson");
query.setParameter(1, patternYouWant);        
query.getResultList();
```

Comment: However "patternYouWant" is also hardcoded, how we can predict all cases, say: "\*alb", "alb\*", "alb???" and so on...

Comment: patternYouWant is parametrised so that you can capture the pattern  you want on your web form and in your code-behind run the name query with the pattern you specified on the form. I hope I'm understanding what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, Ashish, you are correctly understanding it. And big thank you for the pointing suitable direction... I am going to try it now.